# How to sync code in all git branches with git mirror

Tags: git

The requirement is simple. I have 2 git repositories one is `smoke` another is `smoke-mirror`. They have been mirrored with following commands.

```sh
git clone --mirror git@github.com:myrepo/smoke.git smoke-mirror
git clone git@github.com:myrepo/smoke.git
cd smoke
git push --mirror git@github.com:myrepo/smoke-mirror.git
```

When there is any change on current branch, I can use `git push --mirror` to sync the code with mirror repo.

But if there is anyone else create a new branch and commit some changes on smoke repo, I try to sync the changes to mirror repo with these commands:

```sh
cd smoke
git pull --all
git push --mirror git@github.com:myrepo/smoke-mirror.git
```

Above cannot sync the new branch to the mirror repo. But when I switch to the new branch and do the same git push --mirror command, it will work.

My question is how do we sync the new branch code without switching to that branch. Because I will automate the process with Jenkins and branches are dynamic, to make the script more efficient and simple I'd like not to include the switching.

Is there any simple way to sync all branches from smoke to smoke_mirror?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any return from your command?

Comment: Are the remote-tracking branches like `origin/foo` pushed to `smoke-mirror`? Before you switch to the new branch `foo`, `refs/heads/foo` does not exist yet. And by default, the push refspecs are like `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` and `refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, while what you need is `refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_description